Is there a graceful way to handle an AnalysisError when using a DOEDriver?
I'm helping somebody who has posed the following question to me and I'd like to get the OpenMDAO team's opinion.
I am running a design of experiments using the DOEDriver for a floating wind turbine. I made a component raise an AnalysisError when entering an invalid region in the model physics. It works and the driver continues nicely, but there's one issue: when the error is raised, the DOE driver continues to the next iteration, recording all outputs with their default values, which at this point are the values at the previous successful iteration (by iteration I mean a pass through the full model). This is already an issue in DOE study, as outputs of the last iteration are "copied" to a new iteration, and if these are two designs of a FOWT, both designs appear to have the same performance.
In a DOE study/design space sweep, I can filter my results out to exclude these iterations, but I can imagine this would be a bigger issue when using an optimisation driver, which would be "misinformed".
Is there an elegant way to set the values of all outputs to something other than the values on the previous iteration in case of an Analysis Error? This may just be relevant for DOEDriver usage.

If the model includes a nonlinear solver over the problematic system, we've successfully countered this in the past by using the restart_from_successful on the solver.
If not it's something we'll have to handle at the driver level. I'll try to make an example of this for the ongoing development of the AnalysisDriver class.
